# Setting R shiny app expiry date by installing through RInno

Tags: r, shiny

I have created installer shiny app through RInno library. Password authentication while installing is also implemented. I am able to install the shiny app in windows machine. 
Currently, I am looking for setting expiry date in an installed shiny app which should not allow an app to use after expiry.
below is the code to create installer...

```
#Source: https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno
# If you don't have development tools, install them
install.packages("devtools")
require(devtools)

# Use install_github to get RInno
devtools::install_github("ficonsulting/RInno",  build_vignettes = TRUE)

# Require Package
require(RInno)

# Build an installer
create_app(app_name = "app", 
       app_dir = "app",
       include_R = T,
       R_version = "3.4.1",  
       dir_out = "app_inst",
       inst_pw = "pass@123"
)
# compile the installer
compile_iss()
```

please help me to implement the same.